# What is the best practices to add new token to an account?

Tags: balances, transfer, faucet, token

So I'm trying to make a faucet for my blockchain. What I'm doing is creating a faucet account with a lot of balances (with the set_balance method from the sudo pallet). When there's a drip request, I transfer some balance from this faucet account to the requested account. Am I doing it right? If not, how should I do it?

Comment: Sounds about right to me.

Comment: I would do it the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same thing as you. And AFAIK it may be the right way to do the faucet.

And also, you can improve your plan with a small balance in the faucet account at first, for example  1000 $XX, and set a low watermark warning threshold, when the balance arrives there, add more balance to the faucet account. In this way, you didn't lock too much token in the faucet account, and can act as a great faucet at the same time.